# Convert current model to JSON in the Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync method within the MVC.NET Core application

Tags: c#, json, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am supposed to create a functionality where the MVC.NET Core application submits the JSON request through a Web API within the public async Task OnPostAsync(Request request) method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Request request)
{    
   if(request.OwnershipActivity == null || request.OwnershipActivity.Ownership == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("OwnershipAnswer", "You must select an option.");               
    }
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        return Page();
    }
    //Do POST to database then redirect to Index
    //Submit JSON
    creturn RedirectToPage("../Index");
}
```

How do I convert a current Model(Form) into a JSON?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json serializer

Comment: This look slike a razor pages question as opposed to a standard MVC question, you need to clarify.

Comment: Nkosi, thank you, I updated the tags, Morten, you hint solved my probelm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be beyond simple

```
string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

Comment: dont forget to add the "using Newtonsoft.Json"

Answer (score 1):

Try use this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Request request)
{    
    ...
    return Json(yourObject);
}
```

See the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1) of the documentation